Most energy efficient way to make a LED blink using a multivibrator
I'm using this LED. I want to make this LED blink at MAX brightness (100 mA) at 1 Hz. I need to use a multivibrator and therefore can't use any IC chips. The circuit is powered by a 3.7V battery with a capacity of 2900 mAh.
So my question is:
How can I make a multivibrator

As energy efficient as possible

Requirements:

Multivibrator with transistors
Blink at 1 Hz
Blink duration: As short as possible, as long as it reaches 100 mA

What I want to achieve with this:
Make the LED blink as often as possible using a fully charged 2200 µF capacitor.
Any help is appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Things to keep in mind:  If you want 100 mA you better make sure it's never on for more than 10 ms.  The Vf of your LED can be as high as 3.5 V (at 100 mA it will be even higher!), with a 3.7 V battery you need to understand this and think about what voltage drops in transistors do.  Is this homework?

@evildemonic the LED should be on for as little time as possible to reduce the energy consumption. It's not really a homework but a little project for which we get a mark.

A stable 1 Hz flash frequency and exact 100 mA current, at the boundary of LED destruction, while the supply voltage is falling (2200 µF capacitor), requires a complex circuit.

"The most efficient LED flasher by far was the National Semiconductor LM3909.".  There are numerous experiments with a discrete version that you should be able to find through Googling.  Doing it the right way, read the "Micropower Design" chapter 14 in the Kindle version of the second edition of "The Art of Electronics". All the building blocks are there. Including some impressive discrete-only designs.

Also helpful, this Discrete 555 from Evil Mad Scientists (a cool kit to put together). You could also start with an astable multivibrator using higher resistance and lower capacitance, to turn on a joule-thief for the "Blink".  put a decent capacitor around the LED to bring back the peaks and not overdrive the LED.

Does your project allow you to use BJT transistors kind of like this instructables or could you use a simple 555 timer circuit? Looking at the first graph in the led's data sheet seems to reveal that you would need to drive the led to 3.9v in order to reach that 100ma. So just keep that in mind.

We are supposed to use BJT transistors like in the given instructable. Problem with this circuit is that it's not really energy efficient. We are not allowed to use any IC's, not even opamps. Because TOn should be as short as possible, the 100 mA should not damage the LED

@SimonMayr We have been trying to point out that a 3.7 V battery will not be enough, when at 100 mA your LED will require 3.9 - 4 V, and that isn't even taking into account the 0.7 V your transistor will drop.
